# Private to Public Member Same Offset?

Tags: c++, access-modifiers, private-members, memory-layout, public-members

Suppose I have a class

```
struct A
{
    consteval static size_t offsetX() {
        return offsetof(A, x);
    }
    consteval static size_t offsetY() {
        return offsetof(A, y);
    }
    consteval static size_t offsetZ() {
        return offsetof(A, z);
    }
    friend class B;
    private: 
        float x, y;
        int z;
};
```

Now suppose I define `B`

```
struct B : private A
{
    using A::x;
    using A::y;
    using A::z;
};
```

Does the ISO C++ Standard guarantee the following will be true:

```
offsetof(B, x) == A::offsetX()
offsetof(B, y) == A::offsetY()
offsetof(B, z) == A::offsetZ()
```

?

Thank you!

Comment: In your example, both `A` and `B` are [standard-layout classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class), I believe. For standard-layout classes, it is guaranteed that the offset of the first member is zero; no padding is allowed at the beginning of the class. So yes, `offsetof(B, x) == A::offset()` should be true because both values are zero.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your right! I hope you don't mind if I update the question to be slightly more complicated?

Comment: Since `B` doesn't have its own members but only those inherited from `A`, and the base subobject `A` must be at offset zero in `B`, then it follows that all members of `A` are at the same offset in `B` as they are in `A`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That seems to work out on the compilers, but I'm unsure if the standard guarantees it in this case. It seems like a functional requirement, but I'm not sure. The argument I could see against would be to avoid "hacky" ways to access private methods.